# Show $f_{n-1}=g_n , n = 1,..,N \iff f_{n-1}+g_{n+1}=f_n + g_n , n = 1,..,N-1 $ where $f,g\in[0,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Is it true that
$$f_{n-1}=g_n ,  n = 1,..,N \iff f_{n-1}+g_{n+1}=f_n + g_n , n = 1,..,N-1
$$
? where $f,g\in[0,1]$  .

It's easy to see the sufficiency  , this may be elementary but I've a hard time showing the necessity . I tried swaping them then suming them , but that's only  telescoping which doen't give the LHS .

You may ignore this but this question actually came from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/601729) where user  `Did` claimed that $*$ and $\dagger$ are equivalent ,  `Did` 's been offline for 3 yrs so I give up asking `Did`  .

Comment: Suppose $f_n = 1$ for all $n$ and $g_n = 0$ for all $n$.  Here we would have $f_{n-1}+g_{n+1}=1+0$ is indeed equal to $f_n + g_n=1+0$ however $f_{n-1}\neq g_n$ as $1\neq 0$

Comment: Yeah, the best you can get is that $f_{n-1}-g_n$ is constant iff $\dots,$ which is obvious since the right hand can be written as $g_{n+1}-f_n=g_n-f_{n-1}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessity is false , from counterexample by `JMoravitz` in the comment . Nonetheless , the RHS implies the LHS with the additional condition that
$\exists k\in \{1,..,N-1\} , f_{k-1} = g_k $  .