# stationary distribution of a specific markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

A chain with states $1,2,...,\rho$ has a matrix whose first and last rows are $(q, p, 0,...,0)$ and $(0,...,0, q, p)$. In all other rows $p_{k,k+1} = p, p_{k, k-1} = q$. Find the stationary distribution.

the stationary distribution $\pi$ satisfies $\pi P = \pi$, however, even for $\rho = 5$ I'm having trouble noticing a pattern for the components of $\pi$ that would lead me to find the stationary distribiution. Some hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Just some thoughts :**

If $\rho < \infty$  then stationary distribution exists . To show this first show non-zero stationary measure must exist , then normalize it .

---

**Method 1:**
find basis of  $ker(I-P)^T$ , then normalize .

**Method 2:**
Stationary measure $\mu$ has to satisfy
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
 \mu_{0}(1-q) =  \mu_{1}q\\
 \mu_{\rho}(1-p) = \mu_{\rho-1}p\\
 \mu_{k} = \mu_{k-1}p + \mu_{k+1}q & \forall k \in [1,\rho-1]\\
\end{array} \right.
$$
When either $p=0$ or $q=0$  , obviously we have $\pi_0=1 , \pi_\rho=1$ respectively .

Otherwise solve the above recurrence relation for $\mu$ , then normalize .

**Method 3:** (not sure) Stationary distribution may be solved from detailed balance equation similar to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107657) .

Because your chain is similar to birth death chain , and we know stationary distribution exists , also we must have $\pi_{0}p =  \pi_{1}q$ .

---

There're probably more ... but you could first try above methods and see if they actually work .